# Can you use SQL Server Development Edition for a website?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, license

I've got a website I'm developing, and it's database driven.  If I use SQL Server Development Edition as the back end, is that "legal"?  I'll be the only developer using the software, but it will be accessed/queried by dozens/hundreds/thousands of other people.

I apologize if this seems rudimentary, but I've never done this outside of a company so I don't really understand product licensing.

Comment: You would require a production license if it is going to be used for production purposes (and a website that will be accessed by people other than you for development counts as production).   That said Denny Cherry answered this one some time ago here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37149/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-sql-server-developer-edition .  In your Development edition will not cut it I am sorry to say.

Comment: No, development edition is for development and testing, you cannot use it in production. You might consider a web host that offers SQL Server hosting, or Azure SQL Database, both of which will be much cheaper than buying proper licenses